# prevent double click submit without disabling the button

Tags: jquery

I have an app that uses a submit button to query an Ajax call. right now if the user clicks too fast it return duplicate results before the button fades away. The user can click a search icon to bring it back and do more searches so I do not want to disable it after use. Here is my code on submit.

```
      function watchSubmit(){
        $('.guidebox-search-form').submit(function(event){
          $('.guidebox-search-results').empty();
          event.preventDefault();
          var query = $(this).find('.guidebox-query').val();
          getSearchDataFromApi(query, displaySearchData);
        });
      }
```

Is there a simple way of preventing the doble click here or should I rewrite this?

Comment: You say you don't want to disable the button after use, but why can't you disable it after use *and* re-enable it once the `getSearchDataFromApi` response comes back?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent double permission with this :

```
$(".guidebox-search-form").one("submit", Your function);
```

thank to this (.one) the submission should be work just one time.
Hope that help !

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as below:

```
function watchSubmit(){
    $('.guidebox-search-form').submit(function(event){
      $('.guidebox-search-results').empty();
      event.preventDefault();
      var query = $(this).find('.guidebox-query').val();
      getSearchDataFromApi(query, displaySearchData);
      $(this).off(event);
    });
}
```

.off() will prevent the execute event second time for same element

Answer (score 0):

To support @toomanyredirects comment, After clicking that button, You have to disable the button while the function is executing.

```
$('.sample-button').click(function(event) {
    var oElement = $(this);
    oElement.prop('disabled', true); // disable button temporarily
    $.when(watchSubmit()).then(function(event) {
        oElement.prop('disabled', false); // enable button after method was successful.
    });
});
```

If you are using a lower version of jQuery, you might need to use this:
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).attr('disabled', false);

Hope this helps for your case.